# How to configrue quartz to record how long jobs took to execute?

Tags: quartz-scheduler

Is there a way to configure jobs in quartz so that quartz records in its database when a jobs started execution and when it finished execution and how long it took to finish.

I have configured quartz in my application to use the container managed job store, and I want to be able to collect stats on how long jobs are taking to complete to make sure that the jobs are scheduled with enough time to run and are meeting their SLA's.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure whether quartz do store the job start,end,execution time in its database tables.
However,you can achieve your requirement by using a jobListener and overriding its JobWasExecuted() method.

```
public void jobWasExecuted(JobExecutionContext context,
JobExecutionException jobException) {
long runtime=context.getJobRunTime();
System.out.println("Job Execution time :"+runtime);
}
```